# How to change the content of a string in python

Tags: python, string, physics

I have a blog in the following website http://ecosdobigbang.com/ where I'll post material that is relevant to Physics students that speak portuguese (the target audience of this post are physics students in lusophone developing countries since they have a lot of difficulties in getting the material).

To this end I use the following python script that was coded by Luca Trevisan http://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/download/ that allows one to write a LaTeX file that is converted into wordpress.com friendly html.

I never learned how to code in python but through trial and error I was able to make a few little modifications that made the final html output more to my liking.

Nevertheless there is one thing that I want to do that I've not able to do thus far.
When the LaTeX file I'm able to use the portuguese class and all the commands that I use are natively translated into portuguese in the LaTeX file, but when I run the script the html output uses the english name for the theorem like environments.

After digging a lot on the web I've finally decided to quit and ask for help. What I want to be able to do is to modify the python script so that the following theorem environments have their portuguese name

Axiom -> Axiom
Theorem -> Teorema
Lemma -> Lema
etc...

It seems to me that the place where I need to change my code is in the following lines:

```
def convertbeginnamedthm(thname,thm) :
  global inthm

  count[T[thm]] +=1
  inthm = thm
  t = beginnamedthm.replace("_ThmType_",thm.capitalize())
  t = t.replace("_ThmNumb_",str(count[T[thm]]))
  t = t.replace("_ThmName_",thname)
  return(t)

def convertbeginthm(thm) :
  global inthm

  count[T[thm]] +=1
  inthm = thm
  t = beginthm.replace("_ThmType_",thm.capitalize())
  t = t.replace("_ThmNumb_",str(count[T[thm]]))
  return(t)
```

but no matter what I'm not able to have the final output that I want.

Sorry to bother you with such a question, but the problem truly defeats me.

Comment: +1 for teaching me the word "lusophone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty approach would be (tested with the `example.tex` provided with the python script) to add

```
t = t.replace("Theorem", "Teorema")
t = t.replace("Lemma", "Lema")
```

in the function `convertbeginthm` just before the `return (t)`.

Comment: Jasper first off all thanks for you answer. Your suggestion worked just fine. I just have a small problem while trying to include characters like "ç", "ã" etc. that I get the following error message: "Non-ASCII character '\xc23' in file... but no encoding declared". How can I declare the encoding so that accented characters are supported?

Comment: Thanks again jasper! I've follwed your link and follwed the instructions. That is to say that i put the following lines of code at the beginning of the script:

#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

Nevertheless, for the word "Definição" it prints "DefiniÃ§ao".

Comment: then you must also make sure that your editor uses the same encoding to store the file.